# RoutingMissingException Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Having a headache with Elasticsearch and Rails.

I have two models I want to do a parent/child relationship and queries for

model Quran::Ayah

```
class Quran::Ayah < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Quran
    has_many :translations, class_name: 'Content::Translation', foreign_key: 'ayah_key'
mapping  do
      indexes :ayah_index, type: 'integer'
      indexes :surah_id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :ayah_num, type: 'integer'
      indexes :page_num, type: 'integer'
      indexes :juz_num, type: 'integer'
      indexes :hizb_num, type: 'integer'
      indexes :rub_num, type: 'integer'
      indexes :text, type: 'string'
      indexes :ayah_key, type: 'string'

      indexes :translations, type: :nested do 
        indexes :text
        indexes :ayah_key
      end

    end
end
```

model Content::Translation

```
class Content::Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Content
    extend Batchelor


    self.table_name = 'translation'
    self.primary_keys = :ayah_key, :resource_id

    belongs_to :resource, class_name: 'Content::Resource'
    belongs_to :ayah, class_name: 'Quran::Ayah'



    mapping :_parent => { :type => 'ayah' } do
      indexes :resource_id, type: "integer"
      indexes :ayah_key
      indexes :text
    end
end
```

Every time I do import, gives me this error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [content-translations]/[translation]/[1]]","status":400}
```